# Starred multiline environments don't work

Tags: support, mathjax, equation

This is a "asking a question so I can answer it" question, hope no one minds.

As you may know, LaTeX provides two versions of most of its equation-like environments: One which updates the equation-numbering-counter and displays the equation number, and one which does not; for minor equations which you don't want to number. For example, this is the difference between `multline` and `multline*`.

Since math.SE doesn't provide equation numbering, I habitually type the starred versions of these commands when using math.SE. This then causes all kinds of bugs, which frustrate me until I rewrite the equation in another manner. What should I do?

---

Here is a list of environments to which this question might be relevant (cribbed from Figure 5.1 in Gratzer's book):

```
equation, gather, multline, align, flalign, alignat
```

I only checked equation and multline.

Comment: Hmmm... I usually use `$$\begin{align*}....\end{align*}$$` and have no problem. *However*, if I don't go into math mode first, then there *are* all sorts of problems, requiring escape characters (e.g., `\\\` for end of lines, etc).

Comment: related: [Support for automatic equation numbering and labeling of equations](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11170/support-for-automatic-equation-numbering-and-labeling-of-equations)

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any problems.

### Equation

Here is an example without the star:

```
\begin{equation} X = Y \end{equation}
```

\begin{equation} X = Y \end{equation}

Here is an example with the star:

```
\begin{equation*} X = Y \end{equation*}
```

\begin{equation*} X = Y \end{equation*}

### Align

Here is an example without the star:

```
\begin{align} X &= Y \\\\ Y &= Z \\\\ \therefore X &= Z \end{align}
```

\begin{align} X &= Y \\ Y &= Z \\ \therefore X &= Z \end{align}

Here is an example with the star:

```
\begin{align*} X &= Y \\\\ Y &= Z \\\\ \therefore X &= Z \end{align*}
```

\begin{align*} X &= Y \\ Y &= Z \\ \therefore X &= Z \end{align*}

### Aligned

Aligned is meant to be used in mathmode, and so avoids needing the doubled backslashes:

```
$$\begin{aligned} X &= Y \\ Y &= Z \\ \therefore X &= Z \end{aligned}$$
```

$$\begin{aligned} X &= Y \\ Y &= Z \\ \therefore X &= Z \end{aligned}$$

Comment: Note the difference: You include the `align` and `align*` environments in double dollars. If you don't use these double dollar signs, the line breaks `\\ ` should be replaced triple backslashes `\\\ ` (one backslash is an escaping character).

Comment: @Theo: already fixed. :-)  In latex, it is an error to use align in mathmode, so I switched to aligned.

Comment: Huh. I'm confused, because I definitely had examples with `multline*` breaking, and I was very happy when this fixed it. But now I can't replicate them.

Answer (score 1):

If you omit the star, there will be no equation number, and everything works fine.

Comment: It might work if you escaped the star with a backslash.

Comment: @qia this shouldn't be necessary, as we modified the source code to explicitly ignore anything inside `$$` blocks a while ago.

Comment: @Jeff: In TeX, you use \begin{equation} with no dollar signs, so people are probably trying to use it without dollar signs here.  I always use dollar signs and aligned (I had to edit my answer to make my code work not only on math.SE but also in latex).  The non-dollar signed snippets in my answer are (now) all valid tex (except for doubled backslashes in the align example).  To my mind, the double dollar is good enough.